# Simon Game in C#

Tags: c#, label, flashing

I've been creating the game Simon in a windows form using C#. I'm having a problem in the labels that blink to show the pattern. When one label is required to blink twice (because it appears in the pattern twice) it will only blink once. Also, in general the labels will sometimes not blink in the correct order they are meant to (i.e the second in the pattern blinks before the first). Any assistance in how to fix this or in general how to improve on my code would be great. I have only been using C# for the last few weeks and it's part of a university project.
Have attached the code and a picture of what the windows form looks like.
[Windows Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qb6se.png)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Simon2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<int> sequence = new List<int>();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int number = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            sequence.Add(rnd.Next(0, 4));
            hey();
        }

        void hey() 
        {
            foreach (int colour in sequence)
            {
                switch (colour)
                {
                    case 0: {
                        timer1.Enabled = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    case 1: {
                        timer2.Enabled = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    case 2: {
                        timer3.Enabled = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    case 3: {
                        timer4.Enabled = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        void pattern(int colour)
        {
            if (sequence[number] == colour)
            {                   
                label1.Text = ("Score: " + sequence.Count);
                sequence.Add(rnd.Next(0, 4));
                number = 0;
                hey();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Fail!");
                Application.Exit();
            }                 
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Red1.BackColor == Color.Transparent)
            {
                Red1.BackColor = Color.Red;
                timer1.Interval = 300;
            }
            else
            {
                Red1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                timer1.Interval = 300;
                timer1.Stop();                  
            }
        }

        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Blue1.BackColor == Color.Transparent)
            {
                Blue1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                timer2.Interval = 300;
            }
            else
            {
                Blue1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                timer2.Interval = 300;
                timer2.Stop();                  
            }
        }

        private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Yellow1.BackColor == Color.Transparent)
            {
                Yellow1.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                timer3.Interval = 300;
            }
            else
            {
                Yellow1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                timer3.Interval = 300;
                timer3.Stop();                 
            }
        }

        private void timer4_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Green1.BackColor == Color.Transparent)
            {
                Green1.BackColor = Color.Lime;
                timer4.Interval = 300;
            }
            else
            {
                Green1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                timer4.Interval = 300;
                timer4.Stop();                  
            }
        }

        private void Red_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pattern(0);             
        }

        private void Blue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pattern(1);
        }

        private void Yellow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pattern(2);
        }

        private void Green_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pattern(3);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide all code. The initial state of your win forms application is unknown to us, eg, what's inside your `InitializeComponent()`  method. Otherwise it's a lot of work for others to reproduce your scenario.

Comment: Also, consider breaking down your question into smaller parts. Solutions to problems are supposed to be helpful for future encounters with the same problem. "Simon Game in C#" is not a very specific problem, whose solution can be reused many times in the future.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not familiar with the game itself, my understanding is that one light after the other has to light up.
My suggestion: Use Thread.sleep (UI will not be responsive while this does it's thing), instead of timers, directly in the switch:

```
switch (colour){
            case 0: {
                Red1.BackColor = Color.Red;
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                Red1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                break;
            }
```

edit:
a better way would be to use a while loop which checks if a certain amount of ms elapsed and put Application.DoEvents(); in there

Comment: Why suggest something that locks up the UI? This isn't necessary (and introduces a frustrating user experience).

Comment: It is only for a couple milliseconds. And how I understand it a sequence is shown during which no interaction is needed (the user will pay attention to what is displayed and not mess with the UI). I see it as a bit too much for the project to do it a different way. You are, of course, free to suggest a better solution.

Comment: No need to duplicate efforts: A quick search here will reveal other questions and answers showing how to create non-blocking async timers. A blocking Sleep in a UI thread is an anti-pattern and you're teaching that anti-pattern to a beginner.